# Objective C convention: When to use For and when to use With

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

According to the Apple [guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) , seems it is confusing, e.g. for method `viewWithTag`

In Java, I would have a method called

```
getViewByTag // Java version, equivalent to viewWithTag in Obj-C
```

But I also found there are some method like `objectForKey`, so why not just use `objectWithKey` instead?

```
getObjectByKey or just get // Java version, equivalent to objectForKey, 
                           // but why not objectWithKey? Or not viewForKey above?
```

Comment: Nice question, btw. This is one of those questions that I needed an answer for, but never thought to ask. Not even ask myself, for that matter.

Comment: Apple programmer Fred always used "for" and Apple programmer Jim always used "with".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my observation

While setting/getting the objects, you use **WITH**.

e.g. For setting of NSMutableArray object

```
 - (id)initWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems
```

While setting/getting the properties for objects, you use  **FOR**.

e.g.For setting value for property of type NSMutableDictionary

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
```

Hope this helps in clearing your doubt

Comment: unfortunately, the methods for `NSDictionary` are `objectForKey:` `setObject:forKey:`,which is no where near Objective-C properties.

Answer (score 5):

I actually think it is much simpler than what most answers think. I think it has less to do with complex programming language specifics, and has more to do with the uniqueness of the object in question.

When you say `viewWithTag:`, you are asking the `UIView` for **any** view that has that tag. There might be several. The `UIView` will return one of 'em.

However, `objectForKey:` (to me) sounds like there should be a single object (or nil) associated with that key. So, the key kinda exists and is bound (tightly coupled) to a single object.

**EDIT:**

There is an answer mentioning the existence of "by", which further implies how the convention has nothing to do with programming language complexities. It's just natural English.

`NSString`'s `stringByAppendingString:`, for example, uses by, only because the function is written with a the verb *appending*. You can't say withAppending, that's bad English.

Comment: I just wanted to offer the word "plurality" to this discussion. It's the one word that first came to my mind, and the concept explained in this answer (+1). As far as "by", that implies action, the other simply imply a selection.

Comment: the new edit teaches people grammar and non-techy stuff.. choose some [other](http://english.stackexchange.com/?as=1) forum

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `with` is used for properties that directly belongs to an object.  A `UIView` has a `tag` property so `viewWithTag:14` could be rephrased as *"Find the view whose tag property is 14"*.

When you put an object in a dictionary, associated to a key, this key is not necessarily part of the object itself. `objectForKey:@"foo"` is a way to say *"Look for an object that's linked to the key "foo"*.

Comment: +1 this is how I would describe it.  `with` means that the value passed in is a property of the target object, whereas `for` means the value passed in is circumstantially associated to the target object.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple guidelines do not make any such claims as to when to use for or with.  The point of the coding convention is to indicate what the types of the arguments may be and to write method signatures which are natural sounding.

The reason for the for or with in the method name is to identify the type or purpose of the first parameter to the method, which helps it read better.

Apple itself uses several conventions but that is the basic purpose, there is no concrete right or wrong just try to identify the first parameter of the method in the method name with either for or with.

And as for Apple conventions - get(whatever) is not even part of the actual conventions, so you could ask when do I use get or not.

Read this http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

also dont forget (by) NSURL urlByAppendingPathComponent etc - get a feel for it and you wont go wrong

Answer (score 0):

You use "with" whenever the parameter is owned or to be owned, or will be a relatively permanent attribute by the object to the left of the "with" word.

- `initWithCapacity` / `arrayWithCapacity` - the capacity will be an attribute of the container object being called and will be relatively permanent (until you add objects to it beyond the initial capacity)
- `viewWithTag` – return a view "having" the specified "tag" attribute.

Whereas you use "for" to denote a looser association between the "desired" object and a "token" object that you use to get to it.
   - `objectForKey` / `attributeForValue` – usually the "object" does not own the key.
   - `documentForWindow` –  the window is owned by the window controller and not the document. Furthermore there could be more than one window for each document.

But for looser associations of multiple
objects of the same type within a single method call, it's customary that you use something like:

```
doSomethingForFoo:withThisOtherFoo:havingYetAnotherFoo:
```

So the order for such complex call is:

1. for
2. with
3. having